# Conversion to struct from double is not possible

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have two questions

(1) Why is the following code generating this error ? where does `double` come from?

```
Error using horzcat
The following error occurred converting from double to struct:
Error using struct
Conversion to struct from double is not possible.

Error in remove_scratch (line 34)
        old1 =  [lines1, max_vertex1] ;
```

(2) how to get rid of this error?

**Relevant Source Code**

```
for n = 1:N      
    % take n-th image
    hough_trf_input = monochrome_image(:,:,n);
    % find straight lines in the image
    [hough_lines, thetas] = hugh_transform(hough_trf_input); 

    %////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    [lines1, max_vertex1] = find_lines(hough_lines, thetas(1));
    [lines2, max_vertex2] = find_lines(hough_lines, thetas(2));
    [lines3, max_vertex3] = find_lines(hough_lines, thetas(3));

    if(n==1)
        old1 = [lines1, max_vertex1];
        old2 = [lines2, max_vertex2];
        old3 = [lines3, max_vertex3];
    else
        oldlen1 = vertex_length(old1(2));
        oldlen2 = vertex_length(old2(2));
        oldlen3 = vertex_length(old3(2));

        newlen1 = vertex_length(max_vertex1);
        newlen2 = vertex_length(max_vertex2);
        newlen3 = vertex_length(max_vertex3);

        if(newlen1 > oldlen1)
            old1 =  [lines1, max_vertex1] ;
        end

        if(newlen2 > oldlen2)
            old2 =  [lines2, max_vertex2] ;
        end

        if(newlen3 > oldlen3)
            old3 =  [lines3, max_vertex3] ;
        end
    end        
end
```

Here `find_lines()` returns a vector whose 1st element is a vector of `line`-structs, and the second element is a vector of two vectors where each vector is 2-element and represents an axis.

Comment: We need to know what the output types are for `find_lines`. Also, shouldn't you be using arrays rather than sequentially numbered variable names like `old1`, `old2`, `old3`? In fact, this might be a job for cell arrays.

Comment: @beaker, `find_lines()` returns a vector whose 1st element is a vector of `line`-objects, and the second element is a vector of two vectors where each vector is 2-element and represents an axis.

Answer (score 2):

one of the variables {`lines1`, `max_vertex1`} is struct and the other is double. from their names I guess `lines1` is struct and `max_vertex1` is double. You can obtain the same error when running:

```
clear
% lines1 is struct
lines1.p1 = 1;
lines1.p2 = 1;
% max_vertex1 is double
max_vertex1 = 5;
old1 =  [lines1, max_vertex1] ;
```

There are several ways to overcome this, for example you can extract the struct fields into double using `struct2array`:

```
old1 =  [struct2array(lines1), max_vertex1] ;
```

Comment: `find_lines()` returns a vector whose 1st element is a vector of `line`-objects, and the second element is a vector of two vectors where each vector is 2-element and represents an axis.